# Python - parallelize sequential composition of functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `A` that has dimension `(N, d)`. I also have a function `f` that takes arrays `(d,)` and returns arrays `(d,)`. I also have a positive integer `M`. I want to generate a new array `B` of dimension `(N, M+1, d)` as follows:

> `B[i, j, :] = f^j(A[i, :])` for `j=0, ..., M`. In other words, the `(i,j)`th point is generated by composing `f` `j` times and applying it to `A[i,:]`. Notice that when `j=0` then `f^0= lambda x: x` so we don't do anything.

It's easy to write this as a for loop, but I want to parallelize this using multiprocessing.

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1234)
N, M, d = 10, 5, 3
A = np.random.randn(N, d)
B = np.zeros((N, M+1, d))

def compose_f(x, j):
    """Applies f j times to x"""
    if j == 0:
        return x
    else:
        output = x
        for jj in range(1, j+1):
            output = f(x)
        return output


for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        B[i, j, :] = compose_f(A[i, :], j)
```

## Attempt

First, I have rewritten the `compose_f` function. This operation is not parallelizable, but we can avoid evaluating the same quantities more than once.

```
def compute_B_slice(x, M):
    """This version computes a whole slice of B."""
    output = np.zeros((M+1, d))
    output[0, :] = x
    for j in range(1, M+1):
        output[j, :] = f(output[j-1, :])
    return output
```

I have then tried using multiprocessing but I am confused.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def worker(params):
   """Helper function."""
   return compute_B_slice(params)

pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
params = [A_row for Arow in A]
B = pool.map(worker, params)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The first thing I did was to rewrite `compose_f` so that I only need to compute each function evaluation once. Adding it now to the question.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have now added a new function, this computes a slice of `B`, and this should make easier to parallelize this operation across rows of `A`.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have now added my attempt at using multiprocessing

Comment: in compute_B_slice, repeated use of `vstack`  is slow.

Comment: @hpaulj You're right, I've edited the code. Now I initialize an empty array and the fill it

Comment: what is wrong with your approach?

Comment: Iterative processes in general cannot be vectorized using `numpy`.  Sometimes there are math tricks for specific functions that will allow vectorization, but any specific shortcut would not be generalizable.  Better to make a compiled `numba` function to speed up iterative processes.